# Removing lines from text file that contain string at beginning and string at end - and keep one

Tags: text-processing, text

It took me a while to word this best.

Problem 1:

Is there a way to find lines in a text file that have the same string at the beginning and the same strings at the end?

Beginning and end strings not necessarily equal to each other.

Text between the two strings is not consistant in number of characters or number of hyphens.

A hyphen is in between notable strings (which I added to my large text file).

For example:

File:

```
  AAAAA-tjhut-ghyut-FILE1.txt
  BBB-fhuj-dnbhg-frt76-FILE2.txt
  AAAAA-ghtujukr-hgute7gr-xhyutt-FILE1.txt
  AAAAA-VGYT-4d7tt-xhyutt-FILE1.txt
  CCCC-fjuk-dryy-fhuj-FILE3.txt
```

Lines to detect:

```
  AAAAA-tjhut-ghyut-FILE1.txt
  AAAAA-ghtujukr-hgute7gr-xhyutt-FILE1.txt
  AAAAA-VGYT-4d7tt-xhyutt-FILE1.txt
```

Problem 2:

Is there a way to remove all but one of the lines containing the duplicate strings at the beginning and end from above?

Before:

```
  AAAAA-tjhut-ghyut-FILE1.txt
  AAAAA-ghtujukr-hgute7gr-xhyutt-FILE1.txt
  AAAAA-VGYT-4d7tt-xhyutt-FILE1.txt
```

After:

```
  AAAAA-tjhut-ghyut-FILE1.txt
```

Big thanks for any advice.

Note: I think using the occurances of the first hyphen and last hyphen can be used to locate the duplicate strings.

Comment: yes, you can use `awk` to process based on first and last field with `-` as separator... give it a shot

Comment: could be there multiple different duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**
The idea:

- loop twice
- on first loop extract index (column 1 and last column)
- count the occurances of the index
- second loop iterate through all lines again (stored inside first loop)
- extract index again from current row
- if index count > 1 do print

Here is my example, store as `example.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  # field separator
  FS="-";
}
{
  # remember row for second loop
  allRows[rowCount++]=$0;

  # relevant columns
  colFirst=$1;
  colLast=$NF;

  # create combined index: first column, space, last column
  # count occurences of combined index
  indexes[colFirst" "colLast]++;
}
END {

  # loop through all input rows
  for(currentRow in allRows) {

    # extract combined index from current row
    arrLen = split(allRows[currentRow],splitted,"-");
    colFirst=splitted[1];
    colLast=splitted[arrLen];

    # output row  if index count of current row > 1
    if (indexes[colFirst" "colLast] > 1) {
    # index count > 1, so print
      print allRows[currentRow];
    }
  }
}
```

Execute like this, if input file is named `input.txt`:

```
awk -f example.awk < input.txt
```

My output:

```
AAAAA-tjhut-ghyut-FILE1.txt
AAAAA-ghtujukr-hgute7gr-xhyutt-FILE1.txt
AAAAA-VGYT-4d7tt-xhyutt-FILE1.txt
```

**Problem 2:**
As far as I understand you only want to keep the first line:

```
awk -f example.awk < input.txt | head -n 1
```

`head`: output the first part of files

`-n 1`: print the first NUM lines, so just 1